# Send packet from server to a specific client using TCP c#

Tags: c#, tcp, server, client, endpoint

I am currently writing a client-server application. The client sends a UDP broadcast message out trying to locate a server, the server sends a UDP broadcast message out identifying its location.

When a client receives a message identifying the servers location it attempts to connect to the server using socket.Connect(remoteEndPoint).

The server listens for these TCP requests on a listening socket and accepts the requests using listensocket.accept(). The clients details get stored in array (including their IP and port number)

The client sends a message to the server with information about the username and password the user entered.

The server checks the database for the username and password and depending on the result sends back a TCP message (this is where it breaks) to the client who sent the request to check the U&P using the listening socket. I am trying to use the below code to send the TCP message but it will not work as i get an error.

```
TCPSocket.SendTo(message, clientsArray[i].theirSocket.RemoteEndPoint);
```

Comment: You can directly call `Socket.Connect(remoteEndPoint)` and catch exceptions to see if the server is open. By this way it would be more simpler. Doing as I said you can completely remove the existence of UDP in your code. And you can send to a connected Client by `clientsArray[i].theirSocket.Send(msg);`. Since `SendTo` is used only in UDP.

Comment: Im only using the UDP to avoid using so many resources on the server side as UDP broadcasting the servers location indefinitely was not a great idea. I know the connection is made fine and the server is open as i can see it on the client side and the server side (message appears on a GUI saying the client is connected) and if the server closes a message appears on the client side. I am trying to send using   ***TCPSocket.SendTo(message, clientsArray[i].theirSocket.RemoteEndPoint);*** which is the exact same as yours but i get the error.

Comment: I said the `SendTo` function is used in **UDP Only**, so you should only use `Send` function as the **Socket using TCP** in my answer. You can completely forget the `SendTo` function, since you are using TCP.

Comment: Thankyou the message sent successfully. I didn't spot the send rather than sendTo in your response sorry. You have been really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about what method you are using.

But in C# there are 2 common classes that can use as server : [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in **TcpClient**

```
...
//Start Server
Int32 port = 13000;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
server.Start();

//Accept Client
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
String data = "Message From Server";
byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

//Send to Client
stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
...
```

and in **Socket using TCP**

```
...
//Start Server
Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress hostIP = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(hostIP, port);
listenSocket.Bind(ep); 
listenSocket.Listen(backlog);

//Accept Client
Socket handler = listener.Accept();

String data = "Message From Server";
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

//Send to Client
handler.Send(msg);
...
```

and in **Socket using UDP**

**You shouldn't use this on your server since you are using TCP**

```
...
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], 11000);

Socket s = new Socket(endPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

String data = "Message From Server";
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
//Send to Client by UDP
s.SendTo(msg, endPoint);
...
```

Comment: @JOsh This is only a simple sample for teaching how to use these classes. The real server don't look like this. The server will be multi-threaded and have one or two threads for each clients.

Comment: So you can create a thread which is used to accept clients, and after accepting clients, you should create a receiving loop thread for the connected client, and maybe store the socket in an array or something.

Comment: When you're going to send to a client, you can get the `Socket` from the array, and send it with [SendTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/eae4f5y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Using TCP means you can't avoid storing multiple Client Sockets, because this is the way it works.

Comment: Thats exactly what is going on in my application (except the threads - i just use a timer) and i do get the socket from the array using .RemoteEndPoint however i get the exception

"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

Comment: After accepting, you can just use `clientsArray[i].theirSocket.Send(msg);` note that the msg is a byte array, same as the **Socket using TCP** part of my answer.

Comment: If you don't accept clients, then your server shouldn't be called as a `TCP Server`. And it requires more efforts on maintaining clients IP and data.

Comment: That's exactly what i am trying but it wont work. Could it be that i am trying to send a message on a listening socket and need to create another TCP socket just for sending messages would that be a solution to the problem and it does accept clients.

Comment: Then it's called `UDP` and if you have a server, this won't be a good choice. Since UDP is widely used on non-server-required connections.

Comment: Im going to edit my question to try and explain more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you get a connection from a client, you'll get a [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). That class has a method [`GetStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx). If you like to send some data to that client, simply write your desired data to that stream.

Comment: okay that seems like it could be what i want. Do i still use the sendTo property of the Listensocket to send data on the stream. I only ask as i didnt see any sendStream property for TcpClient.

Comment: In [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/eae4f5y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it says that `SendTo` is to "sends a connectionless datagram to the specified remote host."

Comment: @JOsh: For communication you simply call GetStream() and then call the desired read and write methods (sync or async) on the given stream. That's it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are using connected socket or a unconnected one. I guess that you're using a connected socket, so you should reference to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/80z2essb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Because using a unconnected scoket is called UDP, and I don't think you want this.

Comment: The listen socket is unconnected.

Comment: @JOsh So which do you want to use TCP or UDP?

Comment: TCP means using a connected socket.

Comment: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) provides reliable, ordered, and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets between applications running on hosts communicating over an IP network. [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) uses a simple connectionless transmission model with a minimum of protocol mechanism. It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes the user's program to any unreliability of the underlying network protocol. There is no guarantee of delivery, ordering, or duplicate protection. - from wikipedia

Comment: @J3soon, the solution you provided is highlighting the problem I've got. In the code you have i cannot see any way that you are differentiating between the clients that you have connected to the server and are only sending back to one client. I need to be able to send a message to a specific client who has connected to the server and the sendTo property should have worked because as you said it "sends a connectionless datagram to the specified remote host." but i don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JOsh I'll explain more under my answer.